# My CSS is not being appiled to my PHP generated code

Tags: php, html, css

I have a class and in that class I have a function that generates the navigation for the user, the navigation changes based on which role your logged in with. My PHP page creates a new instance of this class then calls the function and the navigation is displayed correctly and links where its suppose to but my CSS isnt being applied. My CSS is:

```
 /* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The Function doing the calling is:

```
public function navigation(){
    if($this->position == "Manager"){
        print "<p><a href='restaurant.php'>Restaurant Details</a></p>";
        print "<p><a href='reviewRequests.php'>Pending Requests</a></p>";
        print "<p><a href='scheduleDesign.php'>Make a Schedule</a></p>";
    }

    print "<p><a href='schedule.php'>Schedule</a></p>";
    print "<p><a href='dayOffRequest.php'>Request a day off</a></p>";
    //print "<p><a href=''>Trade a shift</a></p>";
    print "<p><a href='availability.php'>Availability</a></p>"; 
    print "<br/><p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";
}
```

***EDIT***
I should mention that this function is in a php file. It is then require_once by another php file that calls the function and displays it

The rest of my CSS is working so I know it has nothing to do with the file itself. I'm thinking that it might have something to do with when the function is being called compared to when the CSS is being loaded.

My CSS is being loaded in the html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Comment: may be you have overwritten with some other styles in your CSS file at bottom. otherwise there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: Can you show us how you link your CSS files?

Comment: php has nothing to do with css, or any client side think so dont consider php.

Comment: Go grab Firebug and see the calculated Stylesheets.

Comment: Can you add the working sample in jsfiddle then it will be easy to work on that?

Comment: Where have you put this CSS?

Comment: I am agree with Antony.Could you add the working sample in jsfiddle?

Comment: I dont know how to add php in jsfiddle

Comment: Put the generated HTML in the question. (view source in your browser). That will help us tell what is going on, and based on that you may be able to find the error in your PHP script. Staring at PHP to imagine how it works, after which you have to imaging what bug there may be in the HTML or CSS is not helpful.

Comment: Ok guys I have just load the site in firefox, before I had only used chrome and firefox displayes the CSS correctly just chrome cant handle it for some weird reason. I have also checked it on jsfiddle and it works correctly as well even in chrome so I dont know why Chrome wont load the real thing correctly

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel dumb it was a cache issue, thanks for the comments and sorry for wasting your time.